# Can I get with a python script what queries users run while logged into Maximo?

Tags: python, t-sql, maximo

I'm trying to narrow down some potential issues in Maximo. Can Python help me get all queries certain users run while they are logged in? If Python can do this can someone please provide an example I can work with?

Comment: Maybe if you specify what you're trying to troubleshoot from the query, then we can give more specific advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to program anything to achieve that.

To show the SQL queries executed by the system (and the users), you need to set the SQL logger to level INFO. Basic config will output the SQL run in the SystemOut file.
You can start with this article:
https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21264064

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The direct, simple answer to your question is, No.

If you don't want to log SQL for all users, as you would get with @JPTremblay's excellent answer, then you should investigate the Configure Custom Logging action of the Logging application. In the associated dialog, on the Thread Logger tab, you should be able to configure UI logging for your particular user, and add the SQL logger in the Thread Logger Details.

Comment: Thank you both very much. These answers were very helpful. I was able to accomplish what I wanted.

Comment: @nooneclose, good StackOverflow practice would be to mark one of the answers as "the" answer, so others know a satisfactory answer was found. If you really found both to be helpful, you should up-vote them.

Comment: "@preacher", I do not know how to do that. I tried to upvote one but since I have less than 15 rep points it does not shows publically.